# Some questions of the proof related to Low-rank approximation on wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

i lost the way when i read the proof of Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem (for Frobenius norm) recorded on wikipedia([enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation)).

i firstly want to know in the following logitic of the proof,
\begin{aligned}\sigma _{i}(A')+\sigma _{j}(A'')&=\sigma _{1}(A'-A'_{i-1})+\sigma _{1}(A''-A''_{j-1})\\&\geq \sigma _{1}(A-A'_{i-1}-A''_{j-1})\\&\geq \sigma _{1}(A-A_{i+j-2})\qquad ({\text{since }}{\rm {rank}}(A'_{i-1}+A''_{j-1})\leq {\rm {rank\,}}(A_{i+j-2}))\\&=\sigma _{i+j-1}(A).\end{aligned}

how to conclude
$${\rm{rank}}(A'_{i-1}+A''_{j-1})\leq {\rm {rank\,}}(A_{i+j-2})$$
And my second question is why above conclusion can get

$$\sigma _{1}(A-A'_{i-1}-A''_{j-1})\geq \sigma _{1}(A-A_{i+j-2})$$

thank for u help in advance.

Comment: To your first question, it generally holds that $\operatorname{rank}(A + B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$

Comment: To the second question, it seems that they're using the result from the previous section, i.e. that $A_{i+j-2}$ is the closest matrix to $A$ with rank at most $i+j-2$ to $A$ relative to the spectral norm. Since $(A'_{i-1} + A_{j-1}'')$ has rank at most $i+j-2$, it follows that $\sigma_1(A - (A_{i-1}' + A_{j-1}''))$ (the spectral norm distance between $A$ and $A_{i-1}' + A_{j-1}''$) is more than $\sigma_1(A - A_{i+j-2})$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thank for u help.but i don't understand how do u know the first inequaility by $rank(A + B) \leq rank(A) + rank(B)$?In my perspective, since $rank(A^\prime_{i - 1}) \leq i - 1$ and $rank(A^{\prime\prime}_{j - 1}) \leq j-1$, we can conclude $rank(A^\prime_{i - 1} + A^{\prime\prime}_{j - 1}) \leq i+j -2$ by using the rank inequaility.but we only know $rank(A_{i+j-2}) \leq i + j -2$ instead of $rank(A_{i+j-2}) = i+j-2$.can u please state more precisly?

Comment: The result of the previous section tells you that $A_i$ is the closest matrix of rank **at most** $i$. So, knowing that $\operatorname{rank}(A_{i-1}' + A_{j-1}'')$ is sufficient.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes,i have known it is enough to clarify the proof.Here is only confused me.

Comment: I mean to write "knowing that $\operatorname{rank}(A_{i-1}' + A_{j-1}'') \leq \operatorname{rank}(A_{i+j-2}) = i+j-2$ is sufficient". I don't understand your most recent comment.

Comment: but i think it is not affect the conclusion. Although $rank(A) < i + j - 2$ is hold,we can also using the result from the previous setion to get the final result as required.

Comment: i want to state that $rank(A_{i+j−2})<i+j−2$ if $rank(A) < i+j−2$.@BenGrossmann